# Unable to create Foreign Key relationship with another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do this,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblPerson](
[ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Personame] [varchar](50) NULL)
[Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
[GenderId] [int] NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblGender]( [id] [int] NOT NULL, [Gender] nvarchar NOT NULL)

Alter table tblPerson Add Constraint tblPerson_GenderId_FK Foreign Key (GenderId) references tblGender(id)
```

I am getting Below Error not sure why

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "tblPerson_GenderId_FK". The conflict occurred in database "Sqlkudavenkat", table "dbo.tblGender", column 'id'.

Comment: The error is clear, there is a record in `tblPerson` with a value in the column `GenderID` that does not exists in `tblGender`. You need to fix that record in `tblGender`first before you can create the foreign key

Comment: If `tblGender`is a new table, than you must populate it first with all values found in the column `GenderID` from `tblPerson`

Comment: i will insert data and add foreign key ,and see how it works

Comment: I would recommend that you not use the name ID as your primary keys. One of my biggest pet peeves is columns changing names between tables. A PersonID is a PersonID no matter what table they are in. Also, the tbl prefix is not a great thing either.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that `tblGender`is new table, in that case you need to populate it with values before you can create the foreign key.

Suppose in tblPerson you have used 2 values in GenderID

```
0 meaning male
1 meaning female
```

then your queries could look like this :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblGender]( [id] [int] NOT NULL, [Gender] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL)

insert into tblGender(id, gender)
select distinct p.GenderID, 
       case when p.GenderID = 0 then 'Male' 
            when p.GenderID = 1 then 'Female'
            else 'it came from outer space' 
       end
from   tblPerson p

Alter table tblPerson Add Constraint tblPerson_GenderId_FK Foreign Key (GenderId) references tblGender(id)
```

Comment: Did you just assume that alien's gender?

Comment: i will insert data and add foreign key ,and see how it works

Comment: @JacobH i didnt get u ?

Comment: @Akula just making a joke about the else 'it came from outer space' part of the query.